# codeigniter 3 first and last link not showing in pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I'm using codeigniter 3 and using hmvc for admin  but problem pagination no showing First a Last link.i could not understand where is the problem

```
$config['per_page'] = 2;
        $config['base_url'] = base_url().'admin/manage-cms';
        $config['num_links'] = 20;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
        $page = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $limit_end = ($page * $config['per_page']) - $config['per_page'];
        if ($limit_end < 0){
            $limit_end = 0;
        } 
        $config['first_link'] = 'First';
        $config['last_link'] = 'Last';

        $data['count_cms']= $this->cms_model->count_cms();
        $config['total_rows'] = $data['count_cms'];
        $data['cms'] = $this->cms_model->get_cms($config['per_page'],$limit_end);  

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

i also updated the code to

```
    $config['per_page'] = 2;
        $config['base_url'] = base_url('admin/manage-cms');
        $config['num_links'] = 20;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
        $config['first_link'] = 'First';
        $config['last_link'] = 'Last';
$data['count_cms']= $this->cms_model->count_cms();
        $config['total_rows'] = $data['count_cms'];
        $data['cms'] = $this->cms_model->get_cms($config['per_page'],$page);  
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

But following problem have found

1)in url, pagination coming like url/2,url/4,url/6 etc
But i trying to show url/1,url/2,url/3
2) I have inserted 9 records in db but still First and Last link is not displayed